# Это сложносочинённые предложения?

Tags: пунктуация, ссп

**Хороший тамада(,) и конкурсы интересные**.

**Цены доступные(,) и качество на высоком уровне**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Хороший тамада, и конкурсы интересные.***

***Цены доступные,  и качество на высоком уровне.***

1. Многое зависит от контекста, но, скорее всего, это ССП, поэтому запятая ставится.

Например:

*Мы с интересом наблюдали за представлением. **Хороший тамада, и конкурсы интересные.** Детям здесь нравится.*

*С отелем мы, кажется,  не ошиблись.  **Цены доступные,  и качество на высоком уровне.***

2. Здесь явное **оценочное значение**, что несвойственно номинативным предложениям, для которых главное — это предметность и бытийность.

**Номинативные предложения** — это односоставные предложения субстантивного типа, главный член которых имеет форму именительного падежа и совмещает в себе функцию наименования предмета и идею его существования, бытия. Значение бытийности является здесь доминирующим.

Там есть **оценочно-бытийные предложения**, но в них значение бытийности сопровождается оценкой. Структурной особенностью этих предложений являются эмоционально-экспрессивные частицы: Какой вздор! Что за чушь! Ай да парень Вот так гости! Тоже мне компания!

3. Номинативные конструкции возможны, но с другим порядком слов, например:

***Хороший тамада  и интересные конкурсы**.  Детям понравилось представление.*

***Доступные  цены  и качество на высоком уровне**. Кажется, мы не ошиблись с отелем.*

Comment: Вот теперь мне понравилось. Про бытийность интересно. В первом ещё возможно, при таких ударениях: *Хороший тамада и кОнкурсы интересные.* Но даже контекст трудно подобрать. Разве что реклама, но при рекламировании такой порядок не используется. Ещё интересно то, что при оценке тамады ударение должно быть на "хороший". Так ведь? Но это не сильно по-русски. Что думаете насчёт моего третьего комментария под другим ответом?

Comment: Сложный вопрос, в этом вы правы, и у меня не сразу получилось подобрать  ответ. Мне помог контекст, я на него ориентировалась, а с ударениями задача никак не решалась.  Я сделала такой вывод. В номинативной конструкции порядок слов должен быть нормальным: согласованное определение в препозиции, а несогласованное после существительного. А вот в ССП варианты возможны, так как там можно перемещать логическое ударение.  Попробуйте прочитать ССП с разными ударениями,  тогда может, тоже придете к такому выводу.  Поэтому приходится строить номинатив именно по позиции определения.

Comment: *подобрать ответ* — весёлый подход))) Подбирают из уже имеющегося. Оно ж не сочетается, какая-то метафора. Если номинативные, в первом должен быть обычный порядок (под другим ответом указано, почему так), а во втором — не важно, если плюнуть на звучание. Если простое предложение, ударение должно быть на прилагательном, тогда оно становится сказуемым. Когда номинативные, оно нейтрально, без эмоций, впечатлений. У номинативных предложений особое произношение. Не произнесут так люди это, даже при обычном порядке слов. Такое разве что для рекламы подходит. Здесь ключевой фактор — наличие эмоций.

Comment: Так что с третьим пунктом не согласен. Там эмоции есть, а номинативная интонация их блокирует. Нужен контекст, где нет впечатлений.

Answer (score 3):

**Да, это ССП**, но запятая не требуется, поскольку ваши ССП состоят из односоставных номинативных предложений.

Сравните с примерами из Розенталя:

> "Хриплый стон и скрежет ярый (П.)"; "Зловещий блеск и пестрота дерев…
> (Тютч.)".

Впрочем, есть вероятность, что в этих предложениях сказуемые-прилагательные, и в таком случае запятая между простыми предложениями должна быть.

Comment: В этих простых предложениях прилагательные могут быть сказуемым (в зависимости от того, как прочитать), тогда оценочная характеристика. Помните, что, когда сказуемое выражено прилагательным, тире факультативно? И с "на высоком уровне" вроде бы тоже так.

Comment: @oleedd Да, я думал насчёт того, что тут сказуемые-прилагательные, но счёл, что односоставные номинативные вероятнее.

Comment: В ответе важно указать все варианты. Хоть даже бредовые, но возможные. Иначе он не полный. Оно очень отличается по звучанию. Улавливаете разницу? Мне кажется, что сказуемые вероятнее. Сказуемые — когда кто-то высказывает своё впечатление, а номинативные — когда реклама. Оно больше похоже на первое. "Цены доступные" немного звучит не по-русски (без ударения на "доступные"), если рекламировать, нужен другой порядок.

Comment: В номинативных предложениях бытийность, то есть ничему не даётся оценка, а здесь даётся. Что-то бытийность не подходит.

Comment: Во втором примере вообще без запятой не получается. Там сложно. Когда простые предложения соединяются, ударение автоматически становится в конце первого и оно неумышленное, поэтому слабое, в каком-то смысле его и нет. А там нужно, чтобы не было ударения на "доступные" (иначе сказуемое), и надо умышленно поставить его на "цены", что нарушает единство фразы.